# Selecting ComboBox option on key press. I would like the selection model to auto scroll/jump to the selected option

Tags: javafx, combobox

**What I have so far:**

When I press for example the C key button, this happens:

[First item starts with C is selected.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ioKwu.png)

The *selectOptionOnKey* (see below) function selected the option that starts with letter C.

**The problem:**

The combo box stores more option that can be displayed at once. So when the option which is selected is not in the displayed area I want the combo box to scroll down/jump to that option but I don't know how to do that.

[Selected an option by pressing a letter key - option is not in the displayed area. **-** This will happen with the current code.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qALUL.png)

[Selected an option by pressing a letter key - option is not in the displayed area. **-** **This is what I want to happen!**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fr8CG.png)

---

***Sample code:***

**Main:**

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{

        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));

        Scene scene = new Scene(root, 850.0, 650.0);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.SingleSelectionModel;
import javafx.scene.input.KeyCode;

public class SampleController implements Initializable {

    @FXML private ComboBox<String> cb;

    //Entered random options
    private final ObservableList<String> options = FXCollections.observableArrayList(
            "Aab",
            "Aer",
            "Aeq",
            "Arx",
            "Byad",
            "Csca",
            "Csee",
            "Cfefe",
            "Cead",
            "Defea",
            "Dqeqe",
            "Fefaf",
            "Gert",
            "Wqad",
            "Xsad",
            "Zzz"
            );

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {

        cb.getItems().addAll(options);

        selectOptionOnKey();
    }

    /* When you press a letter key
    *  this method will search for an option(item) that starts with the input letter key 
    *  and it selects the first occurrence in combo box
    */
    public void selectOptionOnKey() {
        cb.setOnKeyPressed(e -> {
            KeyCode keyCode = e.getCode();

            if (keyCode.isLetterKey()) {
                char key = keyCode.getName().charAt(0);

                SingleSelectionModel<String> cbSelectionModel = cb.getSelectionModel();

                cbSelectionModel.select(0);

                for (int i = 0; i < options.size(); i++) {
                    if(cbSelectionModel.getSelectedItem().charAt(0) == key) {
                        // option which starts with the input letter found -> select it
                        cbSelectionModel.select(i);
                        /* Before exiting the function it would be nice if after the selection,
                           the combo box would auto slide/jump to the option which is selected.
                           I don't know how to do that. */
                        return;
                    }
                    else
                        cbSelectionModel.selectNext();
                }   
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**FXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>

<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.171" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="SampleController">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="cb" layoutX="300.0" layoutY="300.0" prefHeight="25.0" prefWidth="173.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. As was already suggested in your previous questions .. do it _now_ - without it's not answereable (there are tons of thingies that could go wrong in your very private context, no way to know which it is)

Comment: okay, now I see what you mean, thanks for the example :) Hmm .. could be a bug or not: navigation keys do trigger a scroll, selection-only generally does not (not even if selected before opening which is the least I would have expected). Need to dig a bit ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As general behaviour, selection in a virtual control  *does not* scroll the selected index/item into the visible region. Slightly astonished that the list in a comboBox' dropdown is no exception to that rule - would have expected at the one that's selected on opening to be visible.

The way out is to scroll the newly selected item in code. This involves:

- get hold of the comboBox' skin
- get the listView by `skin.getPopupContent()`: while that method is public, its return type is an implementation detail ..
- call `list.scrollTo(index)`

A code snippet, could be called whenever the selection changed, f.i. in your key handler:

```
cbSelectionModel.select(i);
ComboBoxListViewSkin<?> skin = (ComboBoxListViewSkin<?>) cb.getSkin();
ListView<?> list = (ListView<?>) skin.getPopupContent();
list.scrollTo(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

I just looked for the exact same question, but selected answer only solves a partial problem. The selection for example does not scroll to the the position when you open a the Combobox.

Here is a more advanced version that also updates the selection for the first time you open the popup and only needs to be set once and not on every spot when select is called.

Helper Function:

```
    private void scrollComboboxListToIndex(ComboBox<?> comboBox, int index) {
        ComboBoxListViewSkin<?> skin = (ComboBoxListViewSkin<?>) comboBox.getSkin();
        ListView<?> list = (ListView<?>) skin.getPopupContent();
        list.scrollTo(index);
    }
```

Add this to your Combobox:

```
    combobox.getSelectionModel().selectedIndexProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
        if (newValue != null) {
            scrollComboboxListToIndex(combobox, newValue.intValue());
        }
    });
    combobox.showingProperty().addListener((observable, wasShowing, isNowShowing) -> {
        if (isNowShowing) {
            Platform.runLater(() -> scrollComboboxListToIndex(combobox, combobox.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex()));
        }
   });
```